# saving different file in micro sd card on arduino board

Tags: sd-card, arduino-uno

I am using sparkfun micro sd card on an arduino uno for data logging for my sensors. I have no problem to save the results from sensors into one file. Now I wish to save files everytime i restart the arduino without delete the first one. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can append data by using the `fopen()` in the append-mode (second parameter "a") or create a new file by checking the existence of the file with Arduinos [exist()](http://arduino.cc/en/pmwiki.php?n=Reference/SDexists) function. If the file exist, you can parse the string, extract for example a postfix number, increment the postfix, built a new incremented filename and check again whether file exists until there is no such file. Then create a new file with the filename. This allows you for example to have multiple ascending files.